# Two guns and multiple actions in Savage Worlds

Tags: savage-worlds

I am very new to Savage Worlds and I am building a **two guns fighter** (2 flintlock guns) in a steampunk-Renaissance setting (Ultima Forsan).

I have the following questions.

**1) Can I shoot with one weapon and reload in the same turn?**
I need 2 turns to fully reload a flintlock gun and according to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/multiple-non-roll-actions-per-turn-in-savage-worlds) answer I can make a non-roll action with an (*optional?*) -2 penality Agility check.

**2) Is this round sequence correct (and possible)?**
Suppose that I have the talent which allows me to shoot with 2 weapons without a penalty and the ambidextrous talent (so that I can shoot with the left hand without a penalty).

- Round 1 -> Shoot with gun 1 and gun 2 (without any penalty)
- Round 2 -> Reload with gun 1 (*I can't reload two times, right?*)
- Round 3 -> Reload with gun 1
- Round 4 -> Shoot with gun 1 (wihout penalty?) and reload with gun 2
- Round 5 -> Reload with gun 2
- Round 6 -> Shoot with gun 2 (wihout penalty?) and reload with gun 1
- And so on...

**3) Is there something which allows me to shorten reload times**

**4) Can I hold a rifle and a gun at the same time?**
And can I shoot with both of them on the same turn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **1) Can I shoot with one weapon and reload in the same turn?**
> I need 2 turns to fully reload a flintlock gun and according to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/multiple-non-roll-actions-per-turn-in-savage-worlds) answer I can make a non-roll action with an (*optional?*) -2 penality Agility check.

Core rules manager Clint Black gave [an official response](http://www.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=45115&p=415850#p415850) clarifying this. If it is a weapon that only takes one round to reload, then you can shoot (with a -2 multi-action penalty) and reload in the same turn, although the GM may choose to require an Agility (-2) check if they feel like it would be difficult to do both in one turn. As for weapons with Reload 2:

> A character couldn't reload a weapon with a Reload of 2 and fire at a -4 penalty. That would be duplicating the same action, reloading, in one round.
>
> So they would reload on one round, and then could finish reloading and fire on the next round at -2.

As for the Agility roll, that's optional and only if the GM feels it's difficult to pull it off in one turn.

> **2) Is this round sequence correct (and possible)?**

I'll break this down into steps:

> - Round 1 -> Shoot with gun 1 and gun 2 (without any penalty)

Because of you said your character could do this (I'm guessing Two-Fisted and Ambidextrous Edges), yes you can do this.

> - Round 2 -> Reload with gun 1 (*I can't reload two times, right?*)

Correct, you can't reload twice in the same round, per Clint's ruling in question 1.

> - Round 3 -> Reload with gun 1

Fine, although it is possible to shoot with a multi-action penalty.

> - Round 4 -> Shoot with gun 1 (wihout penalty?) and reload with gun 2

Shooting with gun 1 would be at a multi-action penalty (so -2 penalty). Also, I would personally as a GM require an Agility (-2) roll for reloading gun 2 because reloading a black powder weapon while you have gun 1 in your other hand seems to be pretty difficult.

This applies to rounds 5 and 6.

> **3) Is there something which allows me to shorten reload times**

In core *Savage Worlds*, no. *Deadlands Reloaded* has the "Speed Load" Edge that allows you to reload as a free action (or reduce the number of rounds by 1 for weapons that require multiple rounds to reload), but unless you are a playing in that setting, you can't use it.

> **4) Can I hold a rifle and a gun at the same time?**

Wibbs clarified this in the comments:

> Yes you can hold them both. You can only use each hand once in a turn, so you could fire the pistol with one hand, and the rifle with the other (-4 penalty for firing a two-handed weapon with one hand). You can't fire the rifle with two hands, as one of them is being used to fire the pistol. The -4 penalty to firing is a standard rule that has been confirmed by Clint a number of times. It derives from the penalty you get with the One-Arm hindrance.

So yes, but your rifle is at a -4 penalty (the same as if you had the One-Arm Hindrance and were firing with just one arm).

Comment: The answer to 4 is yes you can hold them both. You can only use each hand once in a turn, so you could fire the pistol with one hand, and the rifle with the other (-4 penalty for firing a two-handed weapon with one hand). You can't fire the rifle with two hands, as one of them is being used to fire the pistol. The -4 penalty to firing is a standard rule that has been confirmed by Clint a number of times. It derives from the penalty you get with the One-Arm hindrance

Comment: @Wibbs Thanks for clarifying this; I've incorporated your comment into the answer and gave you credit.

Comment: Wonderful and detailed answer! Sorry for the edge names but I have the ruleset in italian :) Just one question: on your comment to round 4 why do I get a -2 penalty? Doesn't Two-Fisted applies to ALL multi actions when paired with another shooting action? Or does it apply to 2 shooting actions only?

Comment: @StockBreak Two-Fisted only applies to shooting twice in a round with two different weapons. It doesn't apply to all multi-actions when paired with another shooting action. So it wouldn't apply for a reload.

Comment: @StockBreak Perhaps it would be a good question on this site to ask for the English names for several words in the Italian version of Savage Worlds. We can probably tell by context what the term means if you give examples (for instance, I knew that you were talking about what the English version calls "Edges" because you mentioned Ambidextrous). I've seen other users on this site with name confusion as well, so I think it would be a helpful question.

Comment: @Thunderforge unfortunately right now I am very new to this game and I don't know much of terms even in my own language :) It will be a good idea in the near future, though.

Comment: @Thunderforge relating to Round 2, can I reload with gun 1 and gun 2? Formally they are 2 distinct actions and not the same action repeated 2 times. My GM let me do it with an Agility check. Is it correct?

Comment: @StockBreak Per [Clint's ruling](http://www.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?p=391255#p391255), you can't do it because both hands are holding a gun. "If an action requires a hand to perform it, then the character must have a free hand to do it. Reloading requires at least one hand to perform, so it would be impossible if both hands were otherwise occupied." I suppose you could if your character was of a race with more than 2 hands.

Comment: @Thunderforge thanks for the reference. Isn't the same thing when reloading just one gun in my first post at round 2? I still have 2 guns with both hands occupied.